# Oracle: FORALL SAVE EXCEPTIONS not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk, forall

I'm trying to handle a FORALL exceptions with the SAVE EXCEPTIONS clause for the INSERT statement. The process contains two simple tables as per the below;

```
CREATE TABLE TBL1   
  ("COL1" VARCHAR2(**40** BYTE) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE TBL2   
  ("COL1" VARCHAR2(**20** BYTE) NOT NULL);
```

The only difference here is the size of a column type. Any attempt made to insert a string value of more than 20 characters would result in handling errors.

Here's the script;

```
DECLARE  
  TYPE REFCURTYPE IS REF CURSOR;
  REFCUR REFCURTYPE;  

  TYPE ASSARRTYPE IS TABLE OF TBL2%ROWTYPE
    INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  ASSARR ASSARRTYPE;

  DML_ERRORS EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(DML_ERRORS, -24381);
BEGIN
  OPEN REFCUR FOR
    SELECT
      COL1
    FROM TBL1;

  FETCH REFCUR BULK COLLECT INTO ASSARR; 
  CLOSE REFCUR;

  FORALL i IN ASSARR.FIRST..ASSARR.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    INSERT INTO TBL2 
      VALUES ASSARR(i);
  COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN DML_ERRORS THEN
      FOR j IN 1..SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
      LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM(-(SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(j).ERROR_CODE)));

      END LOOP;    
      COMMIT;
END;
```

Somehow, when executing the below block for a data set of more than just one record of 20+ chars, I only receive this single error message;

> "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: Bulk Bind: Truncated Bind"

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: to ask the obvious, is tbl1.col1 defined as a different datatype as the column in tbl2 leading to a buffer overflow? If so it is blowing up on the BULK COLLECT, not the FORALL

Comment: Hi Michael, when having both tables 40 Bytes/Chars everything is working fine, it might indicate that the BULK is correct. What I've done is more or less the same as per the "Example 12-13 Handling FORALL Exceptions After FORALL Statement Completes" from Oracle's site: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#LNPLS879)

Comment: Yes, what you are fetching must fit into your collection container first. If you change your definition of TYPE ASSARRTYPE IS TABLE OF TBL2%ROWTYPE to be TBL1%Rowtype since you ARE fetching from tbl1 then the bulk collect will work and the errors will instead occur on the Forall insert - where you want  them

Comment: Michael, you were right, that was the issue. Changing the definition as per your comment resolves the problem. Many thanks.